# Angular.js reset button no effect on ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How is it possible to delete the ul element with the reset button in the following code

```
<html ng-app>

    <head>
        <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="Ctrl">Enter text and hit enter:
            <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" />
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
            <input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="(key,val) in ret">{{key}} = {{val}}</li>
            </ul>
        </form>
        <script>
            function Ctrl($scope) {
                $scope.ret = {}

                $scope.reset = function() {
                    $scope.ret = {}
                }

                $scope.submit = function() {
                    var str = $scope.text;
                    var ret = $scope.ret
                    for (x = 0, length = str.length; x < length; x++) {
                        var l = str.charAt(x);
                        ret[l] = (isNaN(ret[l]) ? 1 : ret[l] + 1);
                    }
                    $scope.ret = ret
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ng-show](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow) to hide it rather than remove it from the DOM.

```
<form ng-init="show=true" ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-submit="submit()">Enter text and hit enter:
    <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" ng-click="show=false" />
    <ul ng-show="show">
        <li ng-repeat="(key,val) in ret">{{key}} = {{val}}</li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. ng-controller="Ctrl" was missing above <form ng-init="show=true" ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="Ctrl">

Comment: @user977828 Added it back. I was playing on jsfiddle and extracted it to the outer wrapper. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you have not wired up the reset method on the controller. It should be like this.

`<input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" ng-click='reset()'/>`

See updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/WdVDh/1/

Comment: Thank you. In $scope.submit function () I had to change to var ret = {} in order to avoid adding to the old the results.